# How to check whether the given word exists in a sentence(string) without using the contains function in golang

Tags: string, go, substring, contains

I need an alternative method instead of strings.contains() to  to check whether the given word exists in a sentence(string).

As an example I need to check the word "can" is inside the sentence "I can run fast" . If I use strings  `strings.Contains("can",  "I can run fast")` this gives true . But `strings.Contains("can",  "I cannot run fast")` also gives true as it contains can . How can I check exactly the word can gives true and cannot gives false in the above mentioned scenario ?

Comment: You could still use contains, but instead of passing "can", pass " can ".

Comment: That depends a lot on **your** definition of "word" and "contains".

Answer (score 3):

Just as a first attempt, you can try using a regular expression:

```golang
import "regexp"

var containsCanRegex = regexp.MustCompile(`\b[Cc]an\b`)

func containsCan(s string) bool {
    return containsCanRegex.MatchString(s)
}
```

Note that this matches title-case, so it matches `"Can I go?"`.

The `\b` in a regular expression matches a "word boundary". It just means there is a word character on one side, and a non-word character, beginning of text, or end of text on the other side.

Note that this will match `"can't"` because `\b` treats `'` as a word boundary (since it's a non-word character). It sounds like this is not what you want. In order to come up with a more general solution, you may want to know just *how general* you want the solution to be. A very basic approach would be to split the words first, and then check if any of those words match `"can"`. You could split the words with a regular expression or by using a text segmentation library.

I don't know how to write a regular expression that would accept `"can"` but reject `"can't"` in a sentence--the `"regexp"` package does not support negative lookahead.

Comment: Hi @Dietrich Epp. Thank you for your answer . But I need a generic method . Not only can and cannot . I'm trying to implement a filter for given set of words .

Comment: You'll want some kind of text segmentation, then. You can use a text segmentation library or make a regexp.

Answer (score 1):

> I need an alternative method instead of strings.contains() to to check
> whether the given word exists in a sentence(string).
>
> I'm trying to implement a filter for given set of words.

Here's a solution which uses simple algorithms for a word. The algorithms can distinguish between "can", "cannot", and "can't".

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "unicode"
)

func newFilter(words []string) map[string]struct{} {
    filter := make(map[string]struct{}, len(words))
    for _, word := range words {
        word = strings.TrimSpace(word)
        word = strings.ToLower(word)
        if len(word) > 0 {
            filter[word] = struct{}{}
        }
    }
    return filter
}

func applyFilter(text string, filter map[string]struct{}) bool {
    const (
        rApostrophe  = '\u0027'
        sApostrophe  = string(rApostrophe)
        sApostropheS = string(rApostrophe) + "s"
        rSoftHyphen  = '\u00AD'
        sSoftHyphen  = string(rSoftHyphen)
        sHyphenLF    = "-\n"
        sHyphenCRLF  = "-\r\n"
    )

    split := func(r rune) bool {
        return !unicode.IsLetter(r) && r != rApostrophe
    }

    text = strings.ToLower(text)
    if strings.Contains(text, sSoftHyphen) {
        text = strings.ReplaceAll(text, sSoftHyphen, "")
    }
    if strings.Contains(text, sHyphenLF) {
        text = strings.ReplaceAll(text, sHyphenLF, "")
    } else if strings.Contains(text, sHyphenCRLF) {
        text = strings.ReplaceAll(text, sHyphenCRLF, "")
    }

    words := strings.FieldsFunc(text, split)
    for _, word := range words {
        if strings.HasSuffix(word, sApostrophe) {
            word = word[:len(word)-len(sApostrophe)]
        } else if strings.HasSuffix(word, sApostropheS) {
            word = word[:len(word)-len(sApostropheS)]
        }
        if _, ok := filter[word]; ok {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    filter := newFilter([]string{"can"})
    text := "I can run fast"
    fmt.Println(applyFilter(text, filter))
    text = "I cannot run fast"
    fmt.Println(applyFilter(text, filter))
    text = "I can-\nnot run fast"
    fmt.Println(applyFilter(text, filter))
    text = "I can't run fast"
    fmt.Println(applyFilter(text, filter))

    filter = newFilter([]string{"cannot", "can't"})
    text = "I can run fast"
    fmt.Println(applyFilter(text, filter))
    text = "I cannot run fast"
    fmt.Println(applyFilter(text, filter))
    text = "I can-\nnot run fast"
    fmt.Println(applyFilter(text, filter))
    text = "I can't run fast"
    fmt.Println(applyFilter(text, filter))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/sQpTt5JY8Qt

Comment: This answer helps me in my case. Thank you so much @rocka2q